# how to get elevation and vertical drop accurately from gps (location manager) in ios?

Tags: ios, location, elevation

I want to get elevation and vertical drop when a user perform skiing or snowboarding i.e. move. I even try API to get latitude, longitude and elevation but it is not accurate.

All the other solutions provided over all the possible sites are not providing accurate solution.